# Making a data structure from a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 6 lists:

```
> dput(ATQ1)
list(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1))
```

I want to write a short program to name them (for instance, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6.) and then create a data frame using this data where each list represent a column of a data frame. Can someone let me know how to do it? I searched for a solution but couldn't get it. Thanks.

Comment: `as.data.frame` and `names` are you friends here, the first converts the list to a data.frame and the second allows you to name the columns.

Comment: Oh wow! Cool! I never knew that it is not required for a data frame to have column names. So it seems, a data frame is just a list of lists of homogeneous size.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich looks to be, just did a search using obvious terms and found links to that post as well… looks sensible, if a bit complicated for a new user of R as the OP seems to be

Comment: @SamMason: yes, that's complicated for efficiency purposes; but that question also has good links to other, less complicated, questions.

Comment: I looked at the answer. I am going to use attributes, as those seem to  work faster and are efficient.

Comment: @Sumit, the response of @user1981275 is fine unless you're dealing with *very* large `data.frame`s.

Comment: Yes, I am using the one he mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your list `l` as follows:

```
names(l) -> c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

and then create a `data.frame`:

```
> data.frame(l)
   A B C D E F
1  1 1 1 1 1 1
2  1 1 1 1 1 1
3  1 1 1 1 1 1
4  1 1 1 1 1 1
5  1 1 1 1 1 1
6  1 1 1 1 1 1
7  1 1 1 1 1 1
8  1 1 1 1 1 1
9  1 1 1 1 1 1
10 1 1 1 1 1 1
11 1 1 1 1 1 1
12 1 1 1 1 1 1
13 1 1 1 1 1 1
14 0 1 1 1 1 1
15 0 1 1 1 1 1
16 0 1 1 1 1 1
17 0 1 1 1 1 1
18 0 1 1 1 1 1
19 0 1 1 1 1 1
20 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

as pointed out already in the comment of Sam Mason